# Where is the information retreived by "uname" stored?

Tags: linux, unix, coreutils

Uname utility in *nix retrieves wonderful meta information about the machine. Where is this information stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [uname command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/uname.html) is actually a front end for a [system call](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/uname.2.html) that does the same thing. The kernel pretty much knows what it is. You can also see this information on, for example /proc/sysinfo.

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.4/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl#L72

Answer (score 3):

Part of the utsname information is also accessible via

> /proc/sys/kernel/{ostype, hostname, osrelease, version, domainname}

see [uname man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/uname.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

The kernel, mostly, where at least the hostname is usually read from `/etc/hostname` or a similar file during bootup.

Answer (score -2):

The uname command retrieved informations are stored in etc/hostname that hostname file contains your machine name.

Comment: No. It contains only the hostname, no kernel related information.